# SQL: How to do a left join and match each left value once only

Tags: sql, postgresql

This type of problem has been perplexing me.

I have 2 tables with money values, and I have to find matching values from another table. If the first table has a value (e.g. 10) three times and the second table has it 2 times, the result I want needs to show 2 values matched, and one is unmatched. It is kind of a many-to-many problem.

I have outlined the problem in a Google Doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/198ZiSGhR6wC2FWNc5Bcr5DTDjx3jCycFq9qlj-eQsEo/edit?usp=sharing

and implemented it in SQL Fiddle including with various failed attempts.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/80353/1

I prefer Postgres, but a generic SQL solution would be fine.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Do some copy'n'paste, add sample table data and the expected result here as well.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add your [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (e.g. SQLFiddle is pretty unreliable for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `row_number` and full join

```
select a.id_a, coalesce(a.value, b.value), b.id_b
from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by value order by id_b) rn
    from b
) b
full join
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by value order by id_a) rn
    from a
) a on b.value = a.value and
       b.rn = a.rn
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/80353/9)